# my function always return current date only

Tags: android

What is problem in my code where method always returns current date

I just want to change format of date

Did I miss something?

```
...
String mydate;

mydate=ConvertToDate("2013/09/25");



  private String ConvertToDate(String dateString){
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date convertedDate = new Date();
        try {
            convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(dateString);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String newdate;
        newdate =  dateFormat.format(convertedDate);
        return newdate;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above code with throws parseException change to this:

```
 private static  String ConvertToDate(String dateString){
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
        Date convertedDate = new Date();
        try {
            convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(dateString);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String newdate;
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

        newdate =  dateFormat1.format(convertedDate);
        return newdate;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You chose wrong pattern. Your date is 2013/09/25 so your pattern should be yyyy/MM/dd.

In your code gives exception and before the try catch block you initialized your date with new Date(). so after exception your convertedDate variable show current date.

You must change

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

To

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd")
```

Your answer in comment. I write here for you.

```
private static String ConvertToDate(String dateString){
      SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
      SimpleDateFormat dateFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
      Date convertedDate = new Date();
      try {
          convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(dateString);
      } catch (ParseException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
      }

      String newdate;
      newdate =  dateFormat2.format(convertedDate);
      return newdate;
  }
}
```

Comment: no i want to change  date format from "2013/09/25" to "2013-09-25"

Comment: this you two times should convert date.  private static String ConvertToDate(String dateString){
      SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
      SimpleDateFormat dateFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
      Date convertedDate = new Date();
      try {
          convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(dateString);
      } catch (ParseException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
      }

      String newdate;
      newdate =  dateFormat2.format(convertedDate);
      return newdate;
  }
}

Comment: i just want a function which take input date like this format "2013/09/25" and return m date like this format  "2013-09-25"

Answer (score 0):

```
// Convert Date formate function
    public static String converDateFormate(String dateString) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY/mm/dd");
        Date testDate = null;
        testDate = sdf.parse(dateString);
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-mm-dd");
        String newFormat = formatter.format(testDate);
        System.out.println("" + newFormat);
        return newFormat;
    }
```

use this:

```
converDateFormate("2013/12/20");
```

Comment: no i just want function take input date in this format ConvertToDate("2013/09/25"); and return my date in this format only
"2013-09-25"

Answer (score 0):

Use `applyPattern`, that's all

```
    String OLD_FORMAT = "yyyy/MM/dd";
    String NEW_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd";


    String oldDateStr = "2013/09/25";
    String newDateStr;

    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(OLD_FORMAT);
    Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse(oldDateStr);
    simpleDateFormat.applyPattern(NEW_FORMAT);
    newDateStr = simpleDateFormat.format(date);

    System.out.println(newDateStr);
```

Output:

```
2013-09-25
```